# XSL to replace value by condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to replace the contents of /SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20/E1EDL37/E1EDL44/CUOBJ with the value of /SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20/E1EDL24/E1EDL43/BELNR but the best I can get is a 'true' with my xsl transformation :(

My xml:

```
<SHPMNT05>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
            <TKNUM>0000287302</TKNUM>
            <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                <VBELN>0081018991</VBELN>
                <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
                    <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000000009645</MATNR>
                    <E1EDL43 SEGMENT="1">
                        <BELNR>0003196597</BELNR>
                    </E1EDL43>
                </E1EDL24>
                <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
                    <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000000009646</MATNR>
                    <E1EDL43 SEGMENT="1">
                        <BELNR>0003196598</BELNR>
                    </E1EDL43>
                </E1EDL24>
                <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
                    <EXIDV>00387112831000247463</EXIDV>
                    <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                        <VBELN>0081018991</VBELN>
                        <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                        <CUOBJ>000000000000000000</CUOBJ>
                    </E1EDL44>
                </E1EDL37>
                <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
                    <EXIDV>00387112831000247470</EXIDV>
                    <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                        <VBELN>0081018991</VBELN>
                        <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                        <VEMNG>5000.000</VEMNG>
                        <CUOBJ>000000000000000000</CUOBJ>
                    </E1EDL44>
                </E1EDL37>
            </E1EDL20>
        </E1EDT20>
    </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

My xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
  
    
    <xsl:template  match="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20/E1EDL37/E1EDL44/CUOBJ">
      <CUOBJ> <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::node()[3]/VBELN=../VBELN and ancestor::node()[3]/E1EDL24/POSNR=../POSNR"/></CUOBJ>
        
       <xsl:for-each select="//E1EDL44">

      </xsl:for-each>
    
    
   </xsl:template>
        

    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current result:

```
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
         <TKNUM>0000287302</TKNUM>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018991</VBELN>
            <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
               <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
               <MATNR>000000000000009645</MATNR>
               <E1EDL43 SEGMENT="1">
                  <BELNR>0003196597</BELNR>
               </E1EDL43>
            </E1EDL24>
            <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
               <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
               <MATNR>000000000000009646</MATNR>
               <E1EDL43 SEGMENT="1">
                  <BELNR>0003196597</BELNR>
               </E1EDL43>
            </E1EDL24>
            <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
               <EXIDV>00387112831000247463</EXIDV>
               <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                  <VBELN>0081018991</VBELN>
                  <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                  <CUOBJ>true</CUOBJ>
               </E1EDL44>
            </E1EDL37>
            <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
               <EXIDV>00387112831000247470</EXIDV>
               <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                  <VBELN>0081018991</VBELN>
                  <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                  <VEMNG>5000.000</VEMNG>
                  <CUOBJ>true</CUOBJ>
               </E1EDL44>
            </E1EDL37>
         </E1EDL20>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

Required result:

```
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
         <TKNUM>0000287302</TKNUM>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018991</VBELN>
            <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
               <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
               <MATNR>000000000000009645</MATNR>
               <E1EDL43 SEGMENT="1">
                  <BELNR>0003196597</BELNR>
               </E1EDL43>
            </E1EDL24>
            <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
               <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
               <MATNR>000000000000009646</MATNR>
               <E1EDL43 SEGMENT="1">
                  <BELNR>0003196598</BELNR>
               </E1EDL43>
            </E1EDL24>
            <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
               <EXIDV>00387112831000247463</EXIDV>
               <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                  <VBELN>0081018991</VBELN>
                  <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                  <CUOBJ>0003196597</CUOBJ>
               </E1EDL44>
            </E1EDL37>
            <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
               <EXIDV>00387112831000247470</EXIDV>
               <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                  <VBELN>0081018991</VBELN>
                  <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                  <VEMNG>5000.000</VEMNG>
                  <CUOBJ>0003196598</CUOBJ>
               </E1EDL44>
            </E1EDL37>
         </E1EDL20>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

Link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aUPRNr

I'm afraid I made a mess with the ancestor::node()[3] part...
Each time I think I'learning something / know how 'to fix it' the challenge becomes too big :(

Update: forgot to mention. there can be more E1EDL44 than E1EDL24 elements. SAP Idoc always starts with E1EDL24 'lines' which shows the lines in a delivery. Then you get E1EDL37 Handling units below with 1 or more E1EDL44 lines on that handling unit. The relation between 24 and 44 is on POSNR.
Also there can be multiple E1EDL20 elements (deliveries) each with e.g. an E1EDL24 with POSNR 10. So the combination E1EDL20\VBELN E1EDL24\POSNR is unique. There is only one E1EDL43 in E1EDL24.

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: AFAICT, there are 2 of each. What is the logic to determine which gets the value of which?

Comment: Also, the question is tagged `xslt-1.0` yet your stylesheet declares `version="2.0"`. Which version can you use?

Comment: Updated xslt version. Copy / paste error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***--  edited in view of clarifications  --***

So, now that we know that there exists a cross-reference between `E1EDL24` and `E1EDL44` in the form of a common value of `POSNR`, we can use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to implement a link between the two.

And, since the value of `POSNR` is unique only within the `E1EDT20` branch, we need to include the unique id of the branch in the key:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="e1edl24" match="E1EDL24" use="concat(POSNR, '|', generate-id(ancestor::E1EDT20))" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CUOBJ">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('e1edl24', concat(../POSNR, '|', generate-id(ancestor::E1EDT20)))/E1EDL43/BELNR"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: P.S. These gobbledygook names are really difficult to work with.

Comment: Thanks for helping me once again Michael. The thing is there can be more E1EDL44  than E1EDL24 elements. SAP Idoc always starts with E1EDL24 'lines' which shows the lines in a delivery. Then you get E1EDL37 Handling units below with 1 or more E1EDL44 lines on that handling unit. The relation between 24 and 44 is on POSNR. Sorry I wans't clear on that. The gobbledygook names is the way SAP named their fields / IDOC if that's what you mean.

Comment: Is the POSNR of a E1EDL24 unique document-wide?

Comment: No, there can be multiple E1EDL20 elements (deliveries) each with e.g. an E1EDL24 with POSNR 10. So the combination E1EDL20\VBELN E1EDL24\POSNR is unique

Comment: Ok. But only one E1EDL43 in E1EDL24, right?

Comment: Correct, only one E1EDL43. AAMOF I need to do the same for E1EDL41 but if I know how to do if for 43 i can re-use it :)

Comment: These clarifications are crucial. No one could have guessed all that from your original post. Anyway, I have amended my answer.